# Flutter Integration Test: How do I test datePicker?

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

Is there any function like we have for textField for assigning the value?

```
 await tester.enterText(find.byKey(const Key('password')), 'Test@124');
```

**CASE:** I want to check selected date is 18 years ago?